# Random CSS value

Tags: javascript, css, random

I have this page where I have 3 triangles made purely out of CSS.
Every time someone loads the page I want the triangle to have different sizes.

Here's the thing illustrated in a JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qaF24/4/

What I would like to do is to randomly set the value of `border-width` of every triangle at page load.

I was thinking doing that with JavaScript with a `Math.random` or something but I didn't manage to do it, nor found some help on the internet (I don't know how to write in Javascript).

[EDIT] I forgot to say that I would like to add a `min` and `max` value.

I would appreciate a little help or guidance for this. Thanks a lot

Comment: To get a reference to an element by a CSS selector, use `document.querySelector`. To change styles of an element, update the appropriate camel-cased property of its `style` property, e.g. `element.style.borderRightWidth = "5px";`. You can indeed use `Math.random` to generate random numbers. With these ingredients you should hopefully be able to get on the right track.

Comment: i would generate the css and then set elmStyle.innerHTML=strGeneratedCSS;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qaF24/5/ with simply `Math.random()` usage

What I've done is:

- random value between 0 and 1and multiply it by 100 (You'll get a border-width in px betwen 0 and 100px)
- set is as css property of each `div' on site

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could I ask you also if I can add `min` `max` value to the `border-width` value?

Comment: Try to think about this one http://jsfiddle.net/qaF24/16/ :) It's quick solution because I'm in hurry, but should works :) Good luck

Comment: Thanks man, I know this must be basic JavaScript but you rock! here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/qaF24/18/ if you feel like it tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `LESS` you declare a variable `@var: Math.random();` and then in your `border-width : @var;`

Answer (score 0):

example code:

```
var triangle = document.querySelector("div");
for (var i = 0; i < triangles.length; ++i)
{
    triangle[i].style.borderWidth = Math.round(Math.random()*200) + "px";
}
```

break down

1. triangle is an `node list`. It contains all the `div` nodes selected with `document.querySelector`.
2. the for lus iterates over every `div`.
3. triangle[i] where `index` is `div` is opened and style property is accessed.
4. A random value is generated between `0` and `200` and rounded up or down to an integer.

Of course your code uses different border widths but this should get you started.

Bonus: you can use this to select the individual divs:

```
document.querySelector("div[class='color']")[0]; //replace color with the colour class names you use.
```

The `[0]` is the first element of the node list. Since it contains only one element we can use this short cut.

Answer (score 0):

This issue would be easier to solve if you used `ids` instead of `classes` so you could use `document.getElementById`. I suggest you replace your `classes` with `ids` instead.

**Part 1**: Getting a random `border-width`.

To accomplish this, use `Math.random` like you suggested in your question. Please note that using `Math.random` returns a value from 0 to 1. It's up to you to determine the range of what you want your border to be. For my response, I'll simply be using a range of `5 pixels` but you can change that value if you want. So to get a value that ranges up to 5, you'll need to multiply `Math.random()` by 5. Be careful though! You'll need to convert this to a string to change the **CSS**.

```
var randomWidth = Math.random()*5;
var width = randomWidth.toString();
```

**Part 2**: Setting the `border-width` of the triangle.
To change the `border-width`, do this for the 3 `ids`:

```
document.getElementById("red").style.borderWidth = width + "px";
```